# Python docker module: How can I create a terminal shell to a docker container in python?

Tags: python, docker, terminal

I would like to create a discord/IRC bot to give random people access to a bash console on a server of mine. To make this a bit less insane I decided to use a docker container so hopefully my server doesn't get rm -rf ed. I am unfortunately stuck on getting IO to /bin/bash on the docker container however.

```
import docker
import time
import asyncio 
client = docker.from_env()

c = client.containers.run(
    image='disbox:main',
    command = "neofetch",
    cpu_count = 1,
    mem_limit = "1g",
    hostname="disbox",
    user = "discord",
    entrypoint="/bin/bash",
    ports = {'80': 8080},
    detach = True
)

# wait for container to start
time.sleep(5)
container = client.containers.get(c.id)

while True:
    cmd = input("\n:")
    res = container.exec_run(cmd, stream=True)
    for line in res:
        print(line.output)
```

This gives a Conflict for url error which I am not sure what that means. I have verified it is not already running elsewhere. I am running python with root (otherwise it gives me a perms error).

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 261, in _raise_for_status
    response.raise_for_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 940, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 409 Client Error: Conflict for url: http+docker://localhost/v1.35/containers/f54feee310d0890b751d9544b020279e1ab35e470b98773f4b160b4c0a470d11/exec

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/docker/models/containers.py", line 193, in exec_run
    resp = self.client.api.exec_create(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/docker/utils/decorators.py", line 19, in wrapped
    return f(self, resource_id, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/docker/api/exec_api.py", line 80, in exec_create
    return self._result(res, True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 267, in _result
    self._raise_for_status(response)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 263, in _raise_for_status
    raise create_api_error_from_http_exception(e)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/docker/errors.py", line 31, in create_api_error_from_http_exception
    raise cls(e, response=response, explanation=explanation)
docker.errors.APIError: 409 Client Error: Conflict ("Container f54feee310d0890b751d9544b020279e1ab35e470b98773f4b160b4c0a470d11 is not running")
```

What this code snippet is intended to do is replicate a bash console in the python console. Where did I go wrong?

edit: The image name is 100% correct its a custom ubuntu SE image with neofetch and some other stuff pre-loaded onto it.

Comment: Are you going to show us the full error output?

Comment: @KlausD. updated with error.

Comment: I guess you are having a stopped container with the same name. `docker ps -a` should show that.

Answer (score 0):

If you run a container with an interactive shell as its main process, but don't specify that the container's stdin should stay open, the shell will exit immediately.  (This is the same as `docker run --entrypoint /bin/bash disbox:main` without the `-it` options.)  When you [create the container](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/containers.html#docker.models.containers.ContainerCollection.run) you need to include the relevant options:

```python
c = client.containers.run(
  ...,
  stdin_open=True,
  tty=True
)
```

The container object then has an [`attach_socket`](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/containers.html#docker.models.containers.Container.attach_socket) method.  This returns a socket-like object that you can `send` to and `recv` from; that connects directly to the container's stdin and stdout.  In your context you can probably use these to directly relay data back and forth between the client process and the container, knowing that it's line-oriented but not otherwise specifically knowing that it's a shell.

You should not need an "exec" type operation here; you are directly interacting with the container process's stdin and stdout.

(Also remember that there's lots of mischief you can get up to with a shell in a container: launching DoS attacks on the host itself, local privilege-escalation attacks against the host kernel, cryptocurrency miners, *etc.*  You have some protection here from being in a container but it's not "safe" if you have any reason to mistrust your end users.)

Comment: I get an error: bytes object has no attribute attach_socket when doing c.attach_socket or c.attach_socket() or client.attach_socket(c). 
Do you have an example of proper usage?